# How to validate string with Joi?

Tags: node.js, joi

I am using `Node Joi` for validation. I am new in node I want to validate `env` to accept only 2 words "Yes" or "No" What changes I have to make in the following code

```
schema = Joi.object().keys({
    app_id: Joi.string().required(),
    env: Joi.string().required()
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`valid`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v9.0.4/API.md#anyvalidvalue---aliases-only-equal) function to define valid values for the field:

```
schema = Joi.object().keys({
    app_id: Joi.string().required(),
    env: Joi.string().valid("Yes", "No").required()
});
```